# Worker Role goes Cycling... after some time, who can I get an alert?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have a worker role deployed that works fine for a period of time (days...) but at some point it stops or crashes, then it can't restart at all and stays "Cycling...". The only solution is to Reimage the Role.

How can I set an automatic alert so I get an email when the Role becomes unresponsive (and Cycling...) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alerts or notifications like this are not available today, but they are being worked on.  If this is causing service interruptions you could always sign up for an external monitoring service which will send you alerts whenever your site is down.

However, I would recommend solving the root cause of the problem rather than just Reimaging it to fix the symptom.  Here is how I would start:

1. You are most likely hitting the issue described in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2012/09/19/role-instance-restarts-due-to-os-upgrades.aspx.  In particular, see #1 under Common Issues where it talks about common causes for a role to not restart properly after being rebooted due to OS updates.  Notice that #1 also talks about how to simulate these types of Azure environment issues (ie. manually do a Reboot from the portal) so you can reproduce the failure and debug it.
2. To troubleshoot the issue I would recommend reading through the troubleshooting series at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.aspx.  Of particular interest to you is probably the "Troubleshooting Scenario 2 – Role Recycling After Running Fine For 2 Weeks"

Answer (score 0):

Azure cannot notify you of such conditions.  Consider placing a try/catch around your loop in the WorkerRole with a catch that can email you in case of an issue.

Alternatively, if you're open to using third party services, consider [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com) (I'm affiliated with the product).  It can alert you in case your instance becomes Unresponsive, Busy, or goes thru other non-Ready status